# How to deploy plugin updates in a scripted workflow for Shopware 6.5

Tags: deployment, plugins, migration, shopware6

We are managing plugins via composer and have different systems (local dev -> testing -> staging -> production). We use currently use the [robo](https://robo.li) taskrunner and have a script for updating a system with potentially new or updated plugins (see also that [news article](https://www.shopware.com/en/news/using-composer-for-plugin-installation-in-shopware/))

```
private const PLUGIN_LIST = [
    'FroshPlatformMailArchive',
    'FroshTools',
     ... and many more ...
];

...

$stack->exec('php bin/console system:update:finish');

$stack->exec('php bin/console plugin:refresh');

foreach (self::PLUGIN_LIST as $pluginName) {
    $stack->exec('php bin/console plugin:install ' . escapeshellarg($pluginName));
    // activate seems - in contrast to install -a check if the plugin is already active
    $stack->exec('php bin/console plugin:activate --skip-asset-build ' . escapeshellarg($pluginName));
    $stack->exec('php bin/console plugin:update --skip-asset-build ' . escapeshellarg($pluginName));
}
```

This takes sometimes quite some time to execute (around 25 seconds for 4 Plugins)

We now figured out that we could do this in a batch:

```
        $pluginNames = implode(' ', self::PLUGIN_LIST);
        $stack->exec('php bin/console plugin:install --no-interaction ' . $pluginNames);
        // activate seems - in constrast to install -a check if the plugin is already active
        $stack->exec('php bin/console plugin:activate --no-interaction --skip-asset-build ' . $pluginNames);
        $stack->exec('php bin/console plugin:update --no-interaction  --skip-asset-build ' . $pluginNames);
```

This helps a little.

Here it would be usefull if the `plugin:*` commands would have an `--all-available` switch to not need to supply each single plugin. We would - if this sounds useful to others here - create a pull request on GitHub.

In generally we are wondering if we doing such deploys "the right way" or if we missing something / there is some standard documentation for this.

There is a [deployer guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/installation-updates/deployments/deployment-with-deployer) but this does not seem to cover enabling plugins.

Answer (score 2):

This looks alright to me. You want to make sure you trigger the lifecycle events of the plugins and I think this is the most reliable way.

There is a command [`plugin:update:all`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/0434670bc736ad1168c59a5bb16153d46f3d3348/src/Core/Framework/Plugin/Command/Lifecycle/PluginUpdateAllCommand.php#L22) which has been part of a recent release. Apparently this should boost performance.

If you can get the output of a command, you could execute `plugin:list` and check the output to reduce the plugins that need to be installed/activated, if any at all.

```php
// will only match if the plugin is installed and activated.
preg_match("/^.*{$pluginName}.*Yes         Yes.*$/m", $output);
```

This command also has an option to output json: `plugin:list --json`

You can decode the output and iterate the plugin list instead if you prefer that.

```php
$inactivePlugins = [];
foreach (json_decode($output, true, 512, \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR) as $plugin) {
    if ($plugin['active']) {
        continue;
    }

    $inactivePlugins[] = $plugin['name'];
}
```

Something like the `--all-available` option you describe sounds like a neat idea. At least I can see the benefit in cases like this. I'd say go for it.